# How to get a post's attached media (audio) ID and insert it into rtmedia shortcode

Tags: php

I am working on a personal project that is set up in a way that each post will have only one media file attached (wav audio) and no imagery or other media at all. I am using rtmedia to transcode the uploaded wav file to mp3 and have the mp3 version playable in the browser with the default WordPress audio player.

I've uploaded an audio file that was given the media ID of 6, and shows up fine when I just hard code the ID for testing into the shortcode using

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[rt_media attachment_id= 6]' ); ?>
```

But I am not entirely sure of the syntax I would need to have the media ID change depending on what post it was attached to.

Something like the following, but doesn't work, nor did I really expect it to.

```
<?php 
$values = get_attached_media( 'audio' );
echo do_shortcode( '[rt_media attachment_id= '. $values[0] .']' );
?>
```

I'm not a coder, so please forgive my sloppiness.

Comment: `get_attached_media()` returns an array of post/`WP_Post` objects, so you should use `$values[0]->ID`, but be sure to check if `$values[0]` is actually set.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. Thank you though.

Comment: I guess I overlooked the fact that I never had any audio attached to a post anyways, I uploaded it via Add Media and just placed the shortcode in my post. Derp. I think I can figure it out using ACF.

Comment: So I added Advanced Custom Fields for file upload field per post. Uploaded a new WAV audio for testing that was given the WordPress media attachment ID 21.

When I paste the following code into my template, it outputs the number 21, which is what I want, just the ID #.

<code><?php
$audio = get_field('audio_upload', $post->ID); 
echo $audio
?></code>

but when I do;

<code><?php
$audio = get_field('audio_upload', $post->ID); 
echo do_shortcode('[rt_media attachment_id= '. $audio .'"]');
?></code> nothing happens

Comment: sorry for my formatting o_o

Comment: Well, you've got an unwanted `"` in the shortcode: `echo do_shortcode('[rt_media attachment_id= '. $audio .'"]')` .. try removing that?

Comment: Ha! It worked, thank you so much! <3